# XCUITest Reading file from bundle form UITest target

Tags: ios, xcode, bundle, ui-testing, xcuitest

I am trying to read a plist file present in Xcode bundle,

**Approach #1 (Didn't work):**
I was using a `static variable`(Line #23 in below screenshot) which returns the path of file present in bundle, It didn't work
[image: Nonworking1]

**Approach #2 (Didn't work):**
Using `Bundle.main` to read a file didn't work
[image: Notworking2]

**Approach #3 (Working solution):**
When I write a `function` (Line #30 in below screenshot) with same lines of code, It works!
[image: working]

Initially I was trying to read file using the `static variable` and wasted **2 days**, until I figured out that using `function` instead of `static variable` would work.

**Questions:**

1. I cant find any relevant documentation, Can anyone explain why this **Approach #1** didn't work?
2. Is the `type(of:)` specific for `object` type not `class`    type?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to read file **from within UITest target** is

**Correct way to read file:**

```
func getPath() -> String?  {
    let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
    let path = bundle.path(forResource: "MockMDM", ofType: "plist")
    return path
}
```

Also let me share the code which seem correct but wont work

**Wrong way to read file:**

```
static var mockMDMFile: [String: Any]? {
    
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "MockMDM", ofType: "plist") {
        let mdmDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as! [String: Any]
        return mdmDict
    }
    return nil
}
```

Reason for failure of wrong way:

- App has **multiple bundles**, and the files present in the UITest target will be part of a different bundle **NOT** Main bundle (`Bundle.main`).

Comment: Why I can't see the difference between the question and answer? 

Comment: :D I found the answer but didnt know why it worked, so posted both working and non-working code in question and my findings in answer, so that it can be helpful for someone who faces similar issue :D, read the question again, it has 2 questions @MojtabaHosseini

Comment: Let me rewrite it for you ☺️ @MojtabaHosseini